# Appending items in a nested python dictionary

Tags: python

I have a nested python dictionary in the following format

```
{"exist":{"name":["a","b"],"country":["US"],"team":["SP","FR"]}, "not_exist":{}}
```

I want to append the following dictionary to the above one:

```
{"exist":{"age":[23,43,45],"sports":["football","rugby"]}, "not_exist":{"title":["Mr","Ms"]}}
```

So that the resulting dictionary looks like

```
{"exist":{"name":["a","b"],"country":["US"],"team":["SP","FR"],"age":[23,43,45],"sports":["football","rugby"]},
 "not_exist":{"title":["Mr","Ms"]}}
```

I tried with `update` method, but its not working.

Comment: Let's see the code where you used `update`

Comment: In addition to the solutions below, while merging dictionaries, I would recommend to be careful of ```dict```'s ```mutable``` nature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `|` operator (for python 3.9+) between dicts:

```py
dct1 = {"exist":{"name":["a","b"],"country":["US"],"team":["SP","FR"]}, "not_exist":{}}
dct2 = {"exist":{"age":[23,43,45],"sports":["football","rugby"]}, "not_exist":{"title":["Mr","Ms"]}}

output = {k: v | dct2[k] for k, v in dct1.items()}
print(output)
# {'exist': {'name': ['a', 'b'], 'country': ['US'], 'team': ['SP', 'FR'], 'age': [23, 43, 45], 'sports': ['football', 'rugby']},
#  'not_exist': {'title': ['Mr', 'Ms']}}
```

For python with version lower than 3.9, you can use:

```py
for k, v in dct2.items():
    dct1[k].update(v)
print(dct1)
```

Note that this modifies your original `dct1`.

Comment: i am getting an error 
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'dict' and 'dict'`

Comment: @imhans4305 Ah then you must be using python < 3.9.

Comment: I am using python 3.8.10

Answer (score 2):

You can traverse the second dictionary and append all those values to the first one as follows:

```
d = {"exist":{"name":["a","b"],"country":["US"],"team":["SP","FR"]}, "not_exist":{}}
d1 = {"exist":{"age":[23,43,45],"sports":["football","rugby"]}, "not_exist":{"title":["Mr","Ms"]}}

for i in list(d1["exist"].keys()):
    d["exist"][i] = d1["exist"][i]
print(d1)
```

**Output:**

```
{'exist': {'age': [23, 43, 45], 'sports': ['football', 'rugby']}, 'not_exist': {'title': ['Mr', 'Ms']}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dict1 = {"exist":{"name":["a","b"],"country":["US"],"team":["SP","FR"]}, "not_exist":{}}
dict2 = {"exist":{"age":[23,43,45],"sports":["football","rugby"]}, "not_exist":{"title":["Mr","Ms"]}}


dict1["exist"].update(dict2["exist"])
dict1["not_exist"].update(dict2["not_exist"])
print(dict1)
```

This simple code snippet did the trick for me?

**Output:**

```
{'exist': {'name': ['a', 'b'], 'country': ['US'], 'team': ['SP', 'FR'], 'age': [23, 43, 45], 'sports': ['football', 'rugby']}, 'not_exist': {'title': ['Mr', 'Ms']}}
```